# how do I change the color of the bottom navigation bar flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to change the color in the bottomNavigationBar when it's selected. Each icon will have a different color. How do I do that?

Here is the code:

```
          bottomNavigationBar: new TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.home),             
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.account_box),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.enhanced_encryption),
              ),
              Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.store),)
            ],
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey[500 ],
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            indicatorColor: Colors.red,


          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a boolean list that represents the tabs, when selecting a tab changes the boolean value for it, and in icon color use a binary to display the color!

```
Icon (
  Icons.home,
  color: checkSelected[0] ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
),
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the color stays